# Swift - Regex - Extract numbers in brackets divided by comma(1,1)(2,3)

Tags: swift, regex

I need to extract the numbers from a string  ex. "(1,1)(3,3)(4,4)". I tried with "\d(,)\d)", but I get the comma too. How can I exclude the comma and make e tuple or an array of arrays [[1,1],[3,3]...

```
let str = "(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)"
let pattern = "\\d(,)\\d"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:pattern)
let results = regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: range)
```

Comment: If you don't want the comma, why are you capturing it?

Comment: Please share the code you are using to see what issue you are having. Note that you may simply strip `(` and `)` and then split with `)(` and you will have your tuples. BTW, is there a comma or dot between `4` and `4`?

Comment: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` would work. Assuming Swift uses the same regex engine as PHP then see https://regex101.com/r/UKp4lC/1

Comment: (4,4) a comma too

Comment: So what's wrong with simply `\d+` then?

Comment: Well.. I get each number with \\d+. I need to make tuples out of (n,n). One way is to iterate through each number and then form tuples

Comment: Please check [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611864/3832970). The solution supports even one number "tuples".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to capture only the digits, replace each occurrence with `"[$1,$2]"`, then insert commas between, wrap the expression in square brackets to get JSON and  decode it

```
let str =  "(1,1)(3,3)(4.4)"
let str1 = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\((\\d+)[.,](\\d+)\\)", with: "[$1,$2]", options: .regularExpression).replacingOccurrences(of: "][", with: "],[")
let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode([[Int]].self, from: Data(("[" + str1 + "]").utf8))
```

The intermediate results are:

- first *replacingOccurrences*: `"[1,1][3,3][4,4]"`
- second *replacingOccurrences*: `"[1,1],[3,3],[4,4]"`
- Argument of *Data(...* `"[[1,1],[3,3],[4,4]]"`

Comment: this works fine, but if you have "(1,1)(3,3)(4,4) 4",  lets say a single digit (one example).. it crashes

Comment: Of course, this information is not part of the question. My approach works only with *Extract numbers in brackets divided by comma*

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```swift
let s = "(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)"
print(s.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\)\s*\("#, with: "|",  options: .regularExpression)
  .trimmingCharacters(in: ["(", ")"])
  .components(separatedBy: "|")
  .map { $0.components(separatedBy: [",", "."]).map { Int($0)!} }
)
```

Output: `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]`.

This will work even if you have a single number inside parentheses. If you have `let s = "(1,1) (3,3)(4.4)(4)"`, the output will be `[[1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 4], [4]]`.

**Details**

- `\)\s*\(` matches `)`, 0+ whitespace chars, `(`, `.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\)\s*\("#, with: "|",  options: .regularExpression)` replaces all these matches with `|`
- `.trimmingCharacters(in: ["(", ")"])` removes `(` and `)` at the start/end of the string
- `.components(separatedBy: "|")` splits the resulting string with `|`
- `.map { $0.components(separatedBy: [",", "."]).map { Int($0)!} }` splits each tuple into constituent numbers and then casts to *Int*.